# How to download .zip files through code?

Tags: c#, ftp, stream, filestream

I have some zip files on an ftp server that I want to download through code but every time I download them and try to open them they are corrupt.

```
    FtpClient conn = new FtpClient();

    conn.Host = ftpFtpServerAddress;
    conn.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpSrcUsername, ftpSrcPwd);
    var files = conn.GetListing(ftpSrcFolder, FtpListOption.Modify | FtpListOption.Size);

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        conn.BeginOpenRead(file.FullName,
            new AsyncCallback(BeginOpenReadCallback), new AsyncArguments()
            {
                Client = conn,
                FileName = file.Name
            });
    }

    private void BeginOpenReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {         
        AsyncArguments args = (AsyncArguments)ar.AsyncState;
        FtpClient conn = args.Client;

        Stream istream = conn.EndOpenRead(ar);
        using (System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(@"C:\temp\" + args.FileName))
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[istream.Length + 10];
            int numBytesToRead = (int)istream.Length;
            fs.Write(bytes, 0, numBytesToRead);
        }                    
    }
```

Comment: Look up the WebClient class. Downloading a file is 3 lines of code.

Comment: I would suspect the problem is with your async call back. I've used similar FTP code to pull zip's and decompress them afterwards with no problems.

Comment: I am using "System.Net.FtpClient;" for the ftp. What would be the problem?

Comment: You aren't reading the bytes from the istream. You define a bytes array and then write it as is to the fs file stream without having a content in the array.

Comment: ah right, hmm what is the best way to read the bytes into the array? I was hoping there would be built in method but I just getting      istream.ReadByte() so guess I have to loop that?

Answer (score 0):

Now with stream.Read. While this method is ok for little files you shouldn´t use it for very large files, because it would fill up your memory very quickly and the byte size of files larger than 2 gb can´t be stored as a int32.

```
    private void BeginOpenReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        AsyncObject args = (AsyncObject)ar.AsyncState;
        FtpClient conn = args.conn;

        Stream istream = conn.EndOpenRead(ar);
        using (System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(@"C:\temp\" + args.filename))
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[istream.Length];
            int bytesread = istream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytesread);
        }
    }
```